# Is the wf $B \to \forall x B$ logically valid?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

So I wanted to know If $B \to \forall x B$ is logically valid. I found this [Tree proof generator](https://www.umsu.de/trees/) website where I can check If a wf is logically valid or if there is an counter-example. I putted in the wf , and it said that it is logically valid.

But , then I checked [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf) by Elliot Mendelson , page 78 , exercise 2.32(a). Here is the exercise.

> Assume that $B$ and $C$ are wfs and that $x$ is not free in $B$. Prove the
> following.
> (a) $\vdash B \to \forall x B$

So I am suspecting that $ B \to \forall x B$ in general (without the condition that $x$ is not free in $B$) cannot be proven in a predicate calculus. So because "Gödel's completeness theorem" (page 91) , $ B \to \forall x B$ is not logically valid. At this point I am confused.

So , Is the wf $$ B \to \forall x B$$ logically valid ?(In the context of mendelson)

Comment: Your concern is correct; if $x$ is free in $B$ the formula is not valid. Counterexample: $x=0 \to \forall x (x=0)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what about the output of the three proof generator? Can you explain why it said that the wf is valid?

Comment: See [Ba → ∀xBx](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#Ba%20%E2%86%92%20%E2%88%80xBx): Ba→∀xBx is invalid.

Comment: Try entering $B(y) \rightarrow \forall x B(x)$ into your proof generator. It doesn't like the multiple uses of $x$, but if you replace it by the equivalent formula $B(x) \rightarrow \forall xB(x)$ it finds a counter-example.

Comment: @Prithubiswas - In your proof generator, if you write $B \to \forall x B$, the proof generator assumes that $B$ is a proposition without free variables (that is, $B$ is a $0$-ary predicate, i.e. a propositional variables). In your proof generator, if you want to say that $B$ is a binary predicate whose free variables are $x$ and $y$, you have to write $B(x,y)$. On the other hand, in Mendelson's book, $B$ stand for an arbitrary formula, possibly with free variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the assurances in the comments that $B\rightarrow\forall x B$ is not generally valid, here's a formal [derivation](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) of the validity of $B\rightarrow\forall x B$ in the case where  $x$ does not occur free in $B.$
[image]

---

**EDIT** (following the comments)

Since $x$ does not occur free in $Ba,$ we could've simply inferred Line 8 directly from Line 1 using the rule $\forall I.$

Here's my full statement of the $\forall I$ inference rule:

- Let $B(\alpha/x)$ denote the result of replacing all free occurrences
  of variable $x$ in formula $B$ with arbitrary term $\alpha$; let $\alpha$ be freely substitutable for $x$ in $B$, and neither occur in $B$ nor occur free in any undischarged assumption.

  Then $B(\alpha/x)$ syntactically entails $\forall xB,$ i.e., $B\vdash\forall xB.$

  (Notice that during the inference, all occurrences of $\alpha$ are
  replaced by $x$).

Comment: That works, but so too does: $$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~Ba}{~~2.~\forall x~Ba\hspace{10ex}\forall\mathsf I,~1}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp When applying the $\forall I$ rule, the conclusion $B$ is forbidden to contain the dummy term $a,$ isn't it?

Comment: It is $x$ that cannot occur free as an arbitrary variable in the predicate unless all of them are being replaced (and none of them occur in the scope of nested quantifiers).

Comment: So, **if** the token $x$ *does not occur* in the predicate, then it is valid to replace *all occurrences* of it with bound variable $x$ in a universal introduction.  (*Somewhat* similar concept to a vacuous truth.)

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, $x$ can only appear bound in Line 1. $\quad$ But this is an entirely separate issue from the fact that ["For (∀I), δ must not appear in in the conclusion ∀ξα(ξ)" (p. 315)](https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/IFL2_LM.pdf). Also:["the use of ∀I requires that we are replacing every instance of the name c with the variable x." (p. 298)](https://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf).

Comment: Indeed, as per the \forallx link (p.298) : When that *arbitrary variable* ($c$) does *not occur* in the predicate, replacing all occurrences of it with the bound variable ($x$) just leaves you with the predicate unchanged.  $Ba[x\backslash c] \equiv Ba$.  :That is: $a$ was *not* the arbitrary variable, it is a free variable used because the Calgury FOL implementation does not accept $B$ alone.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Oh yes, I now see that $a$ need not be the dummy variable (small correction to your last remark: it need not even be a free variable); the important point (being conveyed by the notation "$Ba$") is of course that $x$ does not occur free (in our case, it doesn't occur at all); as such $Ba\vdash\forall x Ba$ *is* a valid single-step inference $(\forall I).$ Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

Your suspicion is correct: If $x$ occurs free in $B$, the formula is invalid.

A formula is valid iff it is true for all interpretations and sequences. $B$ may hold of one object and not hold of another. Then the sequence which assigns $x$ to that object satisfies $B(x)$ but not $\forall x B(x)$, and thereby $B(x) \to \forall x B(x)$ is false under that sequence (and hence invalid):